# how to display array items whthout knwoing its number?

Tags: php, arrays

How to display an array content without using a while loop? coz I don't know how items are within, and without using the function print_r() that displays items with a specific way: array([0]=>..)
 I want to display items one by one, exemple: PHP - Ajax - JSON - DOM, u got it?
How to achieve that guys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $value){...}
```

[See the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Oups, I solved it, just used count($tab) function, that return array length!
My bad, Thanks!